Vuforia Model Tracking with Magic Leap 2
I'm new on this forum and I'm working on model target with Vuforia.
In Unity, I created a simple project for ML2 using the Magic Leap Project Setup Tool. Then I added the Vuforia engine. When I test the Image Target object everything works fine, but when I replace it with the Model Target object nothing happens.
Does anyone have an idea, or an example project that works on a simple model like a cube ?
I tested with OpenXR and MLSDK and the result is the same.
Perception Snapshots option is enabled.
The different models created with Model Target Generator are all validate with the iOS app Vuforia Creator. All models are working fine in this App.
Unity Editor version: 2022.3.45f1
ML2 OS version: 1.10.0
Unity SDK version: 2.4.0
Host OS: MacOS
Thanks

Hi, did you try the Digital Eyewear Sample (https://developer.vuforia.com/library/platform-support/vuforia-digital-eyewear-sample)? It includes a Model Target scene. If that works, I would just copy that setup into your own project. Also, what does the Unity log say? It should say if the Model Target was created.

Hi, yes I tried the Digital Eyewear Sample and replacing the differents models with a simple cube and it seems to work.  The application indicates the tracking of the object. But the bounding box is not displayed superimposed with the cube but very far from it. Do you have any idea what this could be causing ?

If the object you are tracking is actually a cube, I would suggest getting a more featured shape. Simple geometries are difficult to keep track and could cause the bounding box or other renders to jump around. Other reasons could be the origin isn't correct, scaling mismatch between Model Target and real object, or that the render assets isn't a child of the Model Target GameObject. Hard to know exactly.

I use the digital eyewear sample and everything works correctly using a more complex model (ML2 controller). I need to record a tracking demonstration video and as soon as I start recording, the application stops and the tracking no longer works. I think that since the model target uses video recording, it must be a problem to start recording in parallel. Is there a way to make a video recording of the application that does the model tracking ?

Ah, well Vuforia Engine pauses when another application is in use. I would just use Vuforia's Session Recording to capture. But if you need the augmentations included in the video, I recommend doing a video capture: https://developer-docs.magicleap.cloud/docs/guides/features/capture-overview/
https://developer.vuforia.com/library/platform-support/recording-and-playback
